# ng-options displaying duplicate characters

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of string or characters like this:

```
$list.Characters = []
var currGroup = String.fromCharCode(65 + $scope.lengthofsomething.length);
            $scope.Characters .push(currGroup);
```

I create dynamically a list when I add something in my other list (lengthofsomethinglist). So I get "A","B","C" as example. Now what happens is this:

```
  <select ng-model="Characters " style="width:50px; color:black" ng-options="Characters[$index] for v in Characters" ng-change="somefucntion($index,v)"> </select>
```

and this list is generated depending on how many items there are in Characters. If I have A,B,C then I have 3 Lists like this.

What happens next every list has its own values BUT the values are like this:

```
First List:
A
A
A
Second List:
B
B
B
Third List:
C
C
C
```

How do I make all lists have A,B,C and not repeating the same?

When I select the 3rd B in list 2, I get the value C, so it is just a display bug, the values are alright. hopefully you get what I want..

Comment: can u create a fiddle or something to show your code in action .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/15mxta8d/5/ it is not working.. but i hope you get the idea

Comment: @iJade http://plnkr.co/edit/fwwAd4bn6z2vxVN2FUL7?p=preview here is a working one

Comment: When I did your plunk, the repeat in options didn't give each select all the options, but it also didn't duplicate them. I'm not entirely sure what the error is... but is this what you're wanting it to look like? http://plnkr.co/edit/qjvR61CI73lA5LMyupbe?p=preview

Comment: @jsuser yeah, but i want A,B,C to be selected something like ng-selected="$index"... but it is not working for me..